# BroadCastReceiver not calling onReceive from external app

Tags: c#, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

I am not sure if this is the correct way of using the BroadCastReceiver

I have nuget project that manage all my serial/wireless communication, one of my libs has bluetooth support, so i have setup BroadCastReceiver in it and whenever it finds a device it invoke an event that could be caught outside the project.

I was able to create a test project to test my lib before making a nuget for it and it worked using the following code

```cs
  _manager = FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<IBTClassicDeviceConnectionManager>();
            _manager.Start();
            _manager.DiscoverBluetoothDevices();
            _manager.AvailableDevicesUpdated += Manager_AvailableDevicesUpdated;
```

```cs
_manager.Start(); // should enable bluetooth and register the external BroadCastReceiver
_manager.DiscoverBluetoothDevices(); // call BluetoothAdapter.StartDiscovery();
_manager.AvailableDevicesUpdated += Manager_AvailableDevicesUpdated; // listen to the broadreceiver BluetoothDevice.ActionFound
```

My nuget project is class library project so it doesnt have Manifest file but i've added annotations to the broadCastReceiver

```cs
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
public class BluetoothReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
```

if i create a new solution and add the nuget the same code that I've wrote in the testapp(withing the same solution as the nuget) wont work.

Comment: Hi , which nuget of bluetooth used .Here is a broadcast receiver about BlueTooth , you can have a look [here](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/blob/master/Source/Plugin.BLE.Android/BroadcastReceivers/BondStatusBroadcastReceiver.cs).

Comment: I've used native library

Comment: So far i concluded you cant use BroadCastReceive in external application